# Segmentation fault on accessing vector class member

Tags: c++, class, vector, segmentation-fault, member

I have a segmentation fault on this line in c++ :

```
vector<TemplateElement*> children = getChildren();
```

Class `That` inherits from abstract class `TemplateElement`
How to fix that ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "strings.h"
#include "aimlthat.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace aiml;

vector<string> That::elements() {
    vector<TemplateElement*> children = getChildren();
    vector<string> elements;

    for (int i = 0, n = children.size(); i < n; i++) {
        string text = children[i]->toString();
        text = trim(text);
        vector<string> vsText = split(text);

        for(int j=0, m=vsText.size(); j<m; ++j) {
            elements.push_back(vsText[j]);
        } 
    }

    return elements;
}
```

/****************************************************************************/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "strings.h"
#include "aimltemplateelement.h"
#include "aimltext.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace aiml;

vector<TemplateElement*> TemplateElement::getChildren() {
    return m_vtChildren;
}
```

/***************************************************************************/

```
#ifndef __AIMLTEMPLATEELEMENT_H__
#define __AIMLTEMPLATEELEMENT_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "strings.h"
#include "aimlelement.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace aiml;

namespace aiml {
    class TemplateElement : public AIMLElement {
    public:
        TemplateElement() {}
        TemplateElement(vector<TemplateElement*> elements);

        vector<TemplateElement*> getChildren();

        virtual string toString() = 0;
    private:
        vector<TemplateElement*> m_vtChildren;
    };
}

#endif
```

/***********************************************************************/

Here is the class `That` :

```
#ifndef __AIMLTHAT_H__
#define __AIMLTHAT_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "aimltemplateelement.h"

using namespace std;

namespace aiml {
    class That : public TemplateElement {
    public:
        That() {}

        vector<string> elements();
    private:

    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I'm curious, how do you populate the `m_vtChildren` vector? Could you give a example of how are using it in your `main`?

Comment: @Rama Here is the error : http://ideone.com/CyJVtB, I've added a pointer to `That that;`. Why it does not work ?

Comment: @simslay Edited my answer, you need to initialize the `That * that;` too! http://ideone.com/0uMWHk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for null pointer:

```
for (int i = 0, n = children.size(); i < n; i++) {
        if(children[i]) //Be sure that children[i] is not null before dereferencing it
        {
          string text = children[i]->toString();
          text = trim(text);
          vector<string> vsText = split(text);

          for(int j=0, m=vsText.size(); j<m; ++j) {
              elements.push_back(vsText[j]);
          }
       } 
    }
```

[EDIT]
From your comment I see that all you need is initialize the pointer to `That` before using it, and btw don't forget to delete it when you finish:

```
That* that = new That();
that->elements();
```

Comment: The segmentation fault happens before on this line : vector children = getChildren();

Comment: @simslay Then you're most likely using an invalid `That`.

Comment: @simslay So post your class `That` please